# How to wait x seconds in 6502 basic

Tags: basic

How do I wait x amount of time in basic 6502?  I am on VICE xpet, and I would like to print a character, wait a little, then delete it, and repeat for a while, as a sort of status indicator.  The only problem is that it deletes to fast so the indicator never shows up.  I've tried looking for such a command on the reference, but there is nothing for just flat out waiting a little bit.  I know that if I make a huge for loop I may be able to slow the machine down enough to do it by brute force, but I'd rather avoid such if possible.  Is there not a better way?
Thanks!

Comment: Something like Thread.sleep(x) in java.  Thanks!

Comment: Based on what @BillHileman wrote - take a look at: https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/TIME - there is a delay subroutine towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: @18AdrianoH: You're getting great info here on SO, but in case you didn't know about it, there's also http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been decades since I've programmed on a 6502 (C-64/VIC-20) but I'm pretty sure even their version of BASIC had the keyword TIMER.  If memory serves, it counts milliseconds, but I could be wrong.  You might have to play with it.  Set a variable equal to TIMER, do a for/next loop to take up some time, then check its value again.  Once you figure out how many ticks occur in a second, you'll be able to make that a constant and then loop until variable = timer start plus constant ticks per second (first setting variable to timer before loop, of course).

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to the system variable TI for timing purposes. Value of the variable incremented automatically in 1/60 seconds. It will not be perfect but it works.

Below example will print current value of TI for each second:

```
10 PRINT "START " TI
20 T0=T1
30 IF TI-T0>=60 THEN PRINT TI;TI-T0 : GOTO 20
40 GOTO 30
```

Comment: wow didn't even know TI existed; was going to suggest taking a look at the Jiffy Clock